# Android service onDestroy method runs on delay after stopService() called

Tags: java, android, service, delay, ondestroy

I am using a service to run a timer that is controlled using the main activity. However, the lines of code that comes after calling `stopService()` seems to run before the `onDestroy()` method in the service.

Here's the code in *MainActivityClass* that calls the `stopService()`:

```
public void onClickLayoutS(View v){
    //ON CLICK LAYOUT S

    //Behaviour
    stopService(intentTimerService);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isSSelected", true).apply();
    updateLayout();
    if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isPlaying", false)){
        runTimerService();
    }
}
```

Where the `runTimerService()` is:

```
public void runTimerService(){
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("intTimeOnBegin", (int) SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()).apply();
    startService(intentTimerService);
}
```

This is the `onDestroy()` method in the *ServiceClass*:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    //RUNS ON SERVICE END

    //Behaviour
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isSSelected", true)){
        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("intSTime", intTime).apply();
    }else{
        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("intPTime", intTime).apply();
    }
    intTime = 0;
}
```

Where `runnable` is:

```
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //RUNNABLE

            //Behaviour
            if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isSSelected", true)){
                //RUNS IF S IS SELECTED

                //Behaviour
                intTime = sharedPreferences.getInt("intSTime", 0) + ((int) SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - sharedPreferences.getInt("intTimeOnBegin", 0));
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("stringSTime", formatTime(intTime)).apply();
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("stringPTime", formatTime(sharedPreferences.getInt("intPTime", 0))).apply();
            }else{
                //RUNS IF P IS SELECTED

                //Behaviour
                intTime = sharedPreferences.getInt("intPTime", 0) + ((int) SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - sharedPreferences.getInt("intTimeOnBegin", 0));
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("stringPTime", formatTime(intTime)).apply();
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("stringSTime", formatTime(sharedPreferences.getInt("intSTime", 0))).apply();
            }

            //Set runnable repeat interval
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    };
```

So presumably, once I call `onClickLayoutS()` in *MainActivity* it should save the value of `intTime` as `"intSTime"` in sharedPreferences. However, this is not the case, when I run the app and call `onClickLayoutS()` it saves the value of `intTime` as `"intPTime"` instead. Why is this? Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: The `stopService()` method - just like `startService()`, `startActivity()`, etc. - is asynchronous, and returns immediately. Execution is not going to wait for the `Service` to stop. You need to account for that in your design.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. Thank you